# Why is it not recomended to use "LIKE" in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I was recently told that it is not  recomended to use the "LIKE" keyword in SQL. is this true? if so why? if it is true are there any alternatives to it?

Comment: Who by - is there a reference we can refer to?

Comment: I don't think there are faster alternatives

Comment: Did the instructor give reasons or actually give conditions on when not to use rather than a blanket not to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is primarily performance.  However, on the other side of the argument, LIKE is standard SQL and should work in all databases.  Because LIKE has to parse the pattern string, it is a bit less efficient than looking for a substring in a longer string (using charindex or instr or your database's favorite function).  However, processors are so fast that this rarely makes a difference now, except perhaps for the largest queries.

The one caution with LIKE is in a join statement (and this is true of the alternatives as well).  In general, database engines will not use an index for a LIKE in a join.  So, if you can express the join clause in a more index-friendly way, then you might see a substantial increase in performance.

By the way, I'm something of an old-timer with the SQL language, and tend to be a person who avoids using it personally.  However, this is not a habit that should be passed on, because there is little basis anymore for avoiding it.

Comment: Are there any faster alternatives to LIKE?

Comment: In SQL Server, I usually use "charindex(<pattern>, <search string>) > 0".  In Oracle and mysql, the function is instr().  But, let me emphasize, the performance difference is very minor (in most databases) and LIKE is standard SQL, which I like to encourage.

Comment: If no wildcards are needed, you can use `LOCATE()` or similar substring function. Other alternatives at least in the MySQL world include `REGEXP` (more powerful, slower), or `MATCH ... AGAINST` (powerful and fast if you use a `FULLTEXT` index). Fast `LIKE` performance requires a char column that is either indexed on its own or is the first component of a multi-col index, with no wildcards at the beginning of the search string (see hectorg87's answer). Each technique can also behave differently with various character encodings too, check the MySQL manual for details.

Answer (score 2):

Specifically in MySQL (and since this has a MySQL tag I guess that's what you are using), when using LIKE on a column which has an Index you should be carefull of not putting a % in front of the string you are matching if you don't have to, because it will kill the possibility of using the Index for looking efficiently, otherwise there is no problem in using LIKE. e.g.

BAD:

```
col_with_index LIKE '%someText'
```

GOOD:

```
col_with_index LIKE 'someText%'
```

Comment: This is known as "being sargable", and is a general rule for `LIKE`, not just a quirk of MySQL.

Comment: @Jon I didn't want to generalize because I don't know for sure for other RDBMS, however I do for MySQL. I'll look into the "being sargable" later. Thanks, it's good to know that.

Answer (score 0):

There are no valid reasons to not use like!!!

The only exception comes when you can use the EQUAL(=) operator to achieve the same results (my_column LIKE 'XYZ').

If you need to use LIKE any other alternative to achieve the same result should cause the same (or even more) performance problems!

So, in those cases, just think if the use of like is necessary and then use it with no hesitations.